# Jesus said, I am the way, the truth, the life (Jn 14:6) - What is the significances of each and implication in their order?

Tags: john

- In the immediate context (Jn 14:1-7), is Jesus saying an evangelism message - how to be saved, or the way of Believers -how should then believers live until entering the kingdom of heaven?

**Text: John 14:6 (ESV)**

"Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me."

Comment: Whole books have been written about this verse : and deservedly so. No brief summary on a website would do the verse justice, in my opinion. I think the question needs more focus, myself.

Comment: @NigelJ - I agree.  It is too vague.

Comment: @NigelJ even if tons of books are written about this verse, still the question is legit and precise: is there any significance in the sequence of those metaphors - “way”, “truth” and “life” - ascribed to the Lord? In fact how else could anybody ask this question? That there can be infinite answers pending on the answerer’s inspiration or education, that’s a completely different issue.

Comment: If there had been some verse in Moses' writings that explained the order, then I don't think that is would have been considered too vague . If there happens to be no such verse, and thus the answer happens to be "there is no hermeneutic answer", then that is the answer. The question looks very (very, very) precise to me. I agree with Levan Gigineishvili, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

They make a logical sequence:

**WAY**: He is the Way, because through following the way of His commandments, which is the way toward eternal and imperishable treasures (Psalm 139:24), not straying from them will lead us to a comprehension of the meaning of those commandments, for they can be known and comprehended only in the process of putting them to practice in our everyday life, which process conducted in Christ, in Him working in our hearts, is metaphorically expressed by the term "way".

**TRUTH**: When the commandment becomes intimately known to us, so as to become lovingly habitual for us through constant practicing, then we can say that we are not only piously obedient to Christ's commandments through faith, but have understood this faith intellectually and existentially, that we have come to the knowledge of those commandments’ truth, which makes us free (John 8:32). Then we can say that we are no more servants, but friends of the Lord (cf. John 15:15).

**LIFE**: When we shall understand that a) practicing of commandments, b) coming to knowledge of those commandments existentially, eventually will lead us to understanding that all that culminates in Christ being enthroned on the throne of our hearts, for we are His throne and temple (cf. 2 Cor. 6:16), so that we shall realize that the very life was given to us for this great aim and purpose, and moreover that Christ is our life and breathing, so that when we do anything good, it is Him co-working with us, and vice-versa, us co-working with Him, who inspires us and urges us for being in this world the rays of Him, the Sun of Righteousness (cf. Malachi 4:2).

Comment: And for some deeper theology: Without God, these three words lose their meaning. Without God, it doesn't matter what we do; we're just a slam-dance of molecules and nothing can change that. Without God, it doesn't matter what we believe, and in fact "believing" is just an arrangement of molecules; truth becomes an illusion. Without God, we're just bags of chemicals, and what we call "life" is just a different arrangement of the same thing. By claiming to be the things which have no meaning unless there is a God, Jesus is claiming divinity.

Answer (score 1):

This is Jesus' answer to Thomas's question:

> Thomas said to him, “Lord, we do not know where you are going. How can we know the way?”
> (John 14:5, ESV)

But, Jesus had described where he was going:

> “Let not your hearts be troubled. Believe in God; believe also in me. 2 In my Father’s house are many rooms. If it were not so, would I have told you that I go to prepare a place for you? 3 And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come again and will take you to myself, that where I am you may be also. 4 And you know the way to where I am going.”
> (John 14:1–4, ESV)

Thus, Jesus was talking about the way to eternal life with the Father.

> Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me. 7 If you had known me, you would have known my Father also. From now on you do know him and have seen him.”
> (John 14:6–7, ESV)

This expansion of "the way" with knowing Christ is an expansion to the whole inner person.

1. The way implies the volition (will) the direction of one's life.  The narrow path to take.
2. The truth implies the cognition (intellect).  Truth is much more than our intellect, but it addresses our intellect.
3. The life implies the emotions, better understood with such feelings as hunger and thirst, which Jesus often addressed.

Thus, Jesus pointed to salvation involving the total human being.